# Android SetBackground color not working

Tags: java, android, colors

android `setBackgroundColor()` keeps crashing my app

```
 View vyoo = (View) v.getParent();
 Button h = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.hateButton);
 Button r = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.rateButton);
 h.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF70AA"));
```

i have tried doing

```
h.setText("hello");
```

however this worked

Comment: What does crash logs or stacktrace say?

Answer (score 0):

Try getResources().getColor(R.color.colorname) ;
Also define the color in ur values/colors.xml file like this

```
<color
        name="color_name"
        >hex_color</color>
```